# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined. How do I fix this?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, undefined

I am using custom filter to create the sort order from  but least first followed by next but getting error `"ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined"`.

Please help me to fix as it's not allowing to render anything on page.

What changes do I need to make to fix this? Any help is appreciated.

table-filter.pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
  name: "tableFilter"
})
export class TableFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(list: any[], filters: any) {
    //console.log("table-filter", list);
    const keys = Object.keys(filters).filter(key => filters[key]);
    const filterUser = (user: { [x: string]: any }) =>
      keys.every(key => {
        if (key == "sdob") {
          return (
            new Date(user["dob"]) >=
            new Date(new Date(filters[key]).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0))
          );
        } else if (key == "edob") {
          return (
            new Date(new Date(filters[key]).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)) >=
            new Date(user["dob"])
          );
        } else if (
          key === "dl" &&
          user["assigned_to"].filter((e: { dl: any }) => e.dl === filters[key])
            .length
        ) {
          return user;
        } else if (key === "score") {
          const low = filters[key] === "20" && user["score"] <= filters[key];
          const medium =
            filters[key] === "50" && user["score"] < 50 && user["score"] >= 21;
          const high =
            filters[key] === "70" && user["score"] < 70 && user["score"] >= 51;
          const veryHigh = filters[key] === "71" && user["score"] >= 71;
          if (low || medium || high || veryHigh) {
            return user[key];
          }
        } else {
          return user[key] === filters[key];
        }
    });    

    if(list) {
      let filterList = list.filter(filterUser);
      list.sort((lhs, rhs) =>this.lowestScore(lhs.assigned_to) - this.lowestScore(rhs.assigned_to));
    }
    //console.log(filterList, list);

    return keys.length ? list.filter(filterUser) : list;
  }
  
  lowestScore(assign: any) {
    //console.log("assign ", assign);
    let filterData = assign.filter(item => Number(item.co_score));
    let leastScrore = Math.min(...filterData.map(item => item.co_score));
    //console.log("least ", leastScrore);
    return leastScrore;
  }
}
```

Comment: put a check at the beginning `if(!filters){ return list}`

Comment: @NileshPatel where do I update this?

Comment: before `const keys = Object.keys(filters).filter(key => filters[key]);`. it may be breaking at one more place.. but try this

Comment: @NileshPatel list is undefined

Answer (score 3):

The error indicates that one of the objects you are calling ".filter" on is undefined. That would be one of these lines:

`const keys = Object.keys(filters).filter`

- will fail if "filters" has no keys. This looks like a likely candidate if you aren't passing filters to your transform function.

`user["assigned_to"].filter`

- will fail if `user` doesn't have this property or if it isn't an array.

`let filterData = assign.filter`

- will fail if `lowestScore` is passed `undefined`

Comment: @randchris thanks for the detailed explanation. can you help me to fix it how should i approach?

Comment: If the failure is repeatable, you can add "console.log" statements to inspect the objects before you access them. If it doesn't make sense that you have an undefined object you need to fix that elsewhere in your code. If it is acceptable, just add a check: ```if( undefined === theObject ) handle_it```. The exact thing depends on where the error is and what you want to happen next.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is complaining this:

```js
return keys.length ? list.filter(filterUser) : list;
```

When your `list` is undefined, and you have `keys`, it will try to do `list.filter`, since `list` is undefined, you got such error.

Comment: n how do I fix this?

Comment: `return list && keys.length ? list.filter(filterUser) : list;`

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your browser, you could also do:

```
return list?.filter(filterUser) || list
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing

```
ng g pipe searchFilter
```